# Background Process/Service

Tags: android, service, process, background, thread-sleep

im making a simple macro android application for my high school final android project and i want to make a  background process that runs every certain amount of time(decided by the user) to update the current location and other few things as a condition to start the action they chosen like to lower the brightness or changes  the smartphone to silent mode or other few action....how to make that process(or Service) and please keep in mind that i am total beginner(i even dont know the difference between a process or service).. so please your answer with example codes if you can.  thanks you ! :D

Answer (score 0):

To do periodic updates/monitoring/whatever, you need to start a service from your app. Here is a brief explanation:

http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/creating-a-sticky-service-long-running-background-tasks.27065/

And here is the long and detailed one:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

You probably need a foreground service, but sticky may work, too, depending on the specific requirements. Here's some basic code to start with (a little different from the way described in the first link, but the same general idea):

Declare your service in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <service android:name="Foo"/>
```

Extend the Service class

```
    public class FooService extends Service {

    ..........

        @Override
    public void onCreate() {

         //if you want this service to run in the foreground so it doesn't get 
             //killed by the system, create a notification, and call this
             startForeground(id, notification); //look at the Service API

             //start your periodic monitoring thread
             ................

        }

        @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

          //do the cleanup here
          ................

    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

          //whatever you need to do when the app calls the start command, 
          //which may happen multiple times, goes here
          ...............

           //this makes sure the process is sticky (see links above for details
           return START_STICKY; 
    }


        ..........


    }
```

In your main activity's onCreate method, do this:

```
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent i= new Intent(context, FooService.class);
    i.putExtra(whetever you want to pass to the service)
    context.startService(i); 
    context.bindService(i, connection, 0); //read the API
```